# pass parameters to record source with query Access2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am relatively new to access and I have been tasked to improve the navigation of the app.

I have a form which is used to open the report.
The record source of the report is as follows,

```
SELECT 
    Projects.Project_Number, 
    Projects.Customer, 
    Projects.End_User, 
    Projects.Engineering_Company, 
    [Merged Ship and Delivery Dates].Sched_Next_Delivery_Date, 
    [Merged Ship and Delivery Dates].Sched_Next_Ship_Date, 
    Projects.QC_Pack_Req, 
    Projects.Target_QC_Pack_Date, 
    Projects.Invoice_QC_Pack 
FROM 
    Projects LEFT JOIN [Merged Ship and Delivery Dates] 
    ON Projects.Project_Number = [Merged Ship and Delivery Dates].Project_Number 
WHERE 
    (((Projects.Project_Number = [Project Number] ))) 
ORDER BY Projects.Project_Number;
```

I am trying to get the report to open up without prompting me every time. There are instances where I need to refresh the report or open it from other forms.
I have tried to use

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Project Control Sheet", _ 
                acViewReport, , _ 
                "[Project_Number]=" & Me.ProjectNumber, , _
                "[Project_Number]=" & Me.ProjectNumber
```

It is still unable to pass the parameters to the record source. Is there anyway for me to pass the parameters to the recordsource(query)?

I have tried to use

> Forms![formName]ProjectNumber

in the `where` statement  but this only works for a single form and I have other forms which opens up this report.

The purpose of refreshing the form is to allow users to view the changes made to the report after they have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `WHERE` clause from the report's Record Source query, you can later filter the rows it returns with the *WhereCondition* option of the `DoCmd.OpenReport` method.

```vb
Dim strWhereCondition As String
strWhereCondition = "[Project_Number]=" & Me.ProjectNumber.Value
Debug.Print strWhereCondition ' <- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
'DoCmd.OpenReport "Project Control Sheet", acViewReport, , strWhereCondition
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="Project Control Sheet", _
    View:=acViewReport, WhereCondition:=strWhereCondition
```

If you want a different approach, you could use a *TempVar*, since your Access version is 2007.

```vb
TempVars.Add "ProjectNumber", Me.ProjectNumber.Value
```

And change the Record Source query to use the *TempVar* ...

```sql
WHERE Projects.Project_Number = [TempVars]![ProjectNumber]
```

Comment: Is this still the preferred method in 2020?